# Как можно отладить запросы к бд в формате QueryBuilder/ActiveQuery для yii?

Tags: yii2, activerecord

добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли инструменты/расширения/плагины позволяющие делать более удобной отладку запросов в формате QueryBuilder/ActiveQuery для yii? пока что печатал результат преобразования в консоль с помощью CreateCommand->rawSql но это не самый эффективный способ как для меня. существуют ли более полные альтернативы?

Comment: а как же дебаггер, неужели не пользуетесь? https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. интересная вещь. сейчас делаю консольные модули поэтому напрямую страницы не могу пользовать